# Negativamento de perguntas

Tags: debate

Da para perceber que aqui no **StackOverflow** 'algumas pessoas' não estão focado em ajudar os outros, muitos se acha superior a todos sai negativando as perguntas de usuários iniciantes.

Qual a necessidade disso? se a pergunta não está bem clara, porque não deixa um comentário pedindo melhora na pergunta. Ou o **StackOverflow** não é para iniciante? Se não quer ajudar, não atrapalha, nós inciantes estamos buscando o melhor.

Ninguém nasce já sabendo de tudo, aposto que um dia vocês que são superior já foram como nós!

> Eu não queria generalizar em nada, até editei minha pergunta e coloquei na forma correta e me desculpa se ofendi alguém, essa não era minha intenção!

Comment: Léo entenda a negativação como uma ferramenta de avaliação da comunidade. Não leve isso como uma punição ou qualquer outra coisa que não a qualidade da pergunta ou resposta no contexto da ideologia da comunidade. Sempre que isso ocorrer você pode editar sua pergunta/resposta e adequá-la... Mas saiba que mesmo perguntas/repostas boas podem ser negativadas...Não encane, somente tente se adequar ao máximo aos requisitos de como perguntar...

Comment: Quase sempre o melhor jeito de evitar negativos em perguntas é ler o [tour] e entender que apesar de bem simples, é a essência do site. Em seguida, uma lida em [ask] e [no tipo de perguntas no escopo](/help/on-topic) ajuda a aprofundar o entendimento. Depois tem a [help], como o @bigown mencionou. O site está cheio de novatos fazendo perguntas boas, com observação nesses princípios. Quase sempre os negativos não tem a ver com o fato da pessoa ser iniciante, e sim de não procurar entender sobre o site que está usando. Claro que injustiças podem acontecer, mas aí só apontando o caso concreto.

Comment: E já digo que negativei essa sua pergunta, você faz acusações sem provar que as mesmas são verídicas, afirmar categoricamente que ninguem aqui está focado em ajudar é no minimo desrespeitoso com os membros que dedicam parte de seu dia aqui, respondendo perguntas, editando e ajudando outros membros, analisando filas de análises, e tudo isso por livre e espontânea vontade, sem receber nada por isso. Entendo que há casos que ocorrem certas injustiças mesmo, mas não é certo condenar a todos por causa do erros de alguns.

Comment: O meta é justamente para este fim, para você questionar alguma coisa que achou injusta, como um voto negativo, um fechamento, comentários, enfim, para estes casos isolados que podem vim a ocorrer, afinal, viver em comunidade, com varias mentes pensando diferente, discordâncias e conflitos podem ocorrer e aqui é o espaço para discutirmos e resolvermos isso. Mas também há de se ter cuidado com a forma de se expressar essa manifestação, o mesmo respeito que a gente deseja que tenham com a gente deve ser aquele que tenhamos para com os outros.

Comment: *Dá para perceber que aqui no StackOverflow não estão focado em ajudar as pessoas, muitos se acha superior a todos sai negativando as perguntas de usuários iniciantes.* -1 por generalizar. Léo, não é desta forma que as coisas vão se resolver, você precisar olhar os negativos de outro angulo (claro que injustiças sempre podem acontecer) porque o downvote é uma ferramenta utilizada para classificar o conteúdo, não considere o downvote como uma ferramenta feita para atacar os iniciantes. Afinal de contas somos todos iniciantes em alguma coisa ;)

Comment: Não era bem assim @diegofm , acho que eu exagerei ai, eu queria dizer 'algumas pessoas', me desculpa pelo o equivoco!

Comment: Não é bem assim.Tem muita gente se beneficiando por ser novato também,porque o usuário,com dó da baixa reputação, começa a sentar votos positivos. Disso não vejo nenhum "novato" reclamando. Mas eu já vi isso acontecer e a pergunta do "novato" estava bem ruim.Então,tem os dois lados da moeda.Há quem faça de birra,há quem faça porque ache justo,há quem faça porque não gostou da pergunta.Também acho que seria legal deixar um comentário avisando em que a pergunta pode ser melhorada,mas isso não significa que quem comentou não possa negativar.É o mecanismo do site, ele serve pra avaliar a pergunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primeiro vou começar com respostas diretas à pergunta e comentário geral sobre o assunto.

É sugerido que a pessoa ajude dentro da possibilidade de cada um. Mas não é obrigatório.

O Stack Overflow também é para iniciantes em programação. Mas ele tem regras. Elas estão na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). Normalmente nem precisaria ler a maior parte porque em geral é o que todo mundo deveria observar em qualquer lugar. Tem algumas peculiaridades nesse site, que não é um fórum.

O site costuma ter uma qualidade de respostas acima do que se encontra por aí porque exige um nível de perguntas um pouco acima também. Nada exagerado. Não queremos a cobrança em exagero.

Há um problema que muitas vezes a pessoa iniciante não quer aprender, ela quer só que as pessoas que estão aqui se virem para fazer para ela o que é dever dela. Tem casos que a pessoa adora a ideia de comunidade se todo mundo trabalhar para ela, mas quando ela é cobrada retribuir, mesmo da maneira que ela pode, ela não tem o menor interesse. A pessoa precisa entender que é uma via de mão dupla.

Os negativos servem para classificar o conteúdo. Eu sei que parece algo ruim, mas é necessário para indicar o que é um conteúdo de qualidade e útil para todos (sim, o site deve atender a todos e não apenas a quem pergunta) e o que não é útil. O negativo não é nada pessoal, é apenas um indicativo de que tem algo errado ali.

Quando tem um negativo, a melhor solução é tentar melhorar o conteúdo. Se ninguém deixou um comentário comente ali pedindo um esclarecimento. Se achar que o conteúdo está bom e o negativo é injusto pode reclamar aqui e eventualmente sinalizar para a moderação avaliar. Mas note que é bem raro um negativo ser injusto.

Quem é iniciante normalmente tem dificuldade de avaliar se o conteúdo é bom ou não. E tem a tendência de achar que o que ele fez está bom quando não está.

Tudo tem dois lados. Da mesma forma que você acha que tem gente que se sente superior, essas pessoas acham que tem pessoas que não se esforçam o suficiente para fazer a pergunta não colocando informações necessárias para responder, não tentou fazer nada, não colocou uma dúvida clara, de acordo com as regras, não procurou ler como o site funciona, não formatou legal, não cuidou da clareza até mesmo do texto, caprichar na ortografia, gramática. O site é para iniciantes em programação, mas não para quem não consegue formular uma pergunta minimamente inteligível.

Se alguém fez um ataque a algum iniciante sinalize, isso não pode. É claro que chegar aqui e atacar as pessoas não ajuda sua causa. Você está podendo para ser tratado melhor, então comece tratando as pessoas melhor. Eu entendo que fique com raiva que não tenha sua dúvida sanada do jeito que queria, mas essa atitude não é boa, você não vai conseguir sensibilizar ninguém assim.

Falando especificamente das suas coisas, pelo que eu vi tem pouca coisa sua negativada. Tem muita coisa removida. Tem uma negativada e removida que não dá nem para questionar os negativos de tão ruim. Tem outra fechada e removida que tentaram salvar, não foi pra frente. Todas sua perguntas que eu vi tem comentários dizendo o que fazer, ou foram apagadas tão rápido que nem deu para alguém ajudar. Não tem negativadas recentes. Quero deixar claro que não vi grandes problemas em coisas suas.

Fora ser algo específico esse debate já ocorreu outras vezes. Sempre aparece alguém defendendo que deve-se ajudar o o máximo que dá. Eu até acho que todo mundo deve fazer isso se quiser. Mas ninguém é pago para ajudar outras pessoas, todos são voluntários, ninguém é obrigado a nada. As pessoas são livre para usar os mecanismos do site dentro das regras.

Eu sou um que defendo a liberdade das pessoas ajudarem até onde dá, tentar se esforçar, mas se for um fardo muito grande ela pode fazer só o básico que é votar, sinalizar, e coisas assim. Tem que defenda o contrário, mas eu sempre disse que é dar esmola com a carteira dos outros, porque essas pessoas pregam isso e depois somem do site deixando o fardo para outras pessoas carregarem. Tanto que muitos usuários que eram muito ativos desistiram totalmente ou parcialmente do site, esses últimos passaram a entrar no site só de vez em quando, e não fazem praticamente nada. Eu sempre disse que isso ia acontecer e acabou acontecendo. Alguns até ajudam ai máximo quando entram, outros nem isso. Mas o grosso do tempo fica na mão de quem participa muito ativamente.

Nem vou falar das pessoas que defendem a ajuda máxima, a todo custo, e em 15 dias elas desaparecem para sempre.

Exigir que pessoas que ajudam voluntariamente tenham que se responsabilizar por todo conteúdo do site, mesmo o ruim não produzido por elas é contraproducente. Quem quer ser ajudado precisa se esforçar. Estamos aqui para evitar que tenha algum problema mesmo quando teve esforço, mas se não teve o esforço o sistema até incentiva o negativo, o fechamento e até a remoção. Até que aqui no SOpt somos bem condescendentes em relação ao SOen.

Muitas chegaram aqui reclamando do jeito que era o site e hoje é um usuário importe no site, o tempo foi mostrando que o jeito do site é o mais adequado. Ele ajuda quem merece e "pune" (essa não é a intenção) quem não quer ou não pode se esforçar em manter a qualidade.

Reforço que dúvidas simples bem de iniciante são algumas das mais respondidas aqui e costumam ser valorizadas. Perguntas mal formuladas não são bem recebidas.

De qualquer forma fica aqui o pedido para as pessoas colaborarem mais com quem não fez boas perguntas, se puderem.

Comment: Excelente resposta bigown!

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua resposta!