# Críticas ao Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: debate, comunidade, qualidade

Desde antes do nascimento deste site já teve críticas, alguns achavam até que não deveriam ter uma versão em português e que todo programador deve ser obrigado ser fluente em inglês. Imagine o que uma pessoa dessas chegar aqui hoje e ver que as pessoas não sabem nem fazer um `if` ou resolver um erro básico de sintaxe.

Temos críticas aos montes, todos os dias. Existem algumas pessoas que reclamam em redes sociais e outros lugares. Em geral não usam e não fazem parte da comunidade, algumas já usaram minimamente mas não usam mais. É comum essas pessoas darem esmola com a carteira dos outros. Elas criticam quem está dando o sangue aqui e acham que devemos fazer mais do que já fazemos. E tem que ser o que elas desejam, mesmo sem elas se esforçarem em nada para colaborar. Sem fazer a parte delas, elas sempre tem todas as soluções, só não mexem um dedo para fazer isto acontecer, elas só querem que seja diferente. Acho um desrespeito e geralmente feito por pessoas que hoje são classificadas por alguns de "floquinho de neve".

Se for diferente, viramos o Yahoo! Respostas. No fundo essas pessoas, mesmo que não intencionalmente, querem destruir o que este site tem de bom.

Se você quer criticar saiba que já fizeram antes, dificilmente você fará algo novo. Se quer desabafar, aqui não é o lugar adequado. Discorde, critique, mas tente fazer algo novo, construtivo e que gere algo positivo.

A crítica funciona melhor se entende a cultura daqui, se é participativo, se faz sua parte.

E no fim somos vistos como arrogantes por alguns, esses nunca tiveram contato com outras áreas - algumas sabem disfarçar bem, mas converse com alguns profissionais mais sinceros dessas áreas... Eu também já achei a nossa área muito pior, mas hoje vejo que isso é generalizado, principalmente em sociedades que prezam majoritariamente pela mediocridade e descomprometimento. O mundo é dividido entre os que gostam da qualidade e os que preferem a mediocridade, os que estão no segundo grupo costumam chamar os que estão no primeiro de arrogantes. Arrogância tem a ver justamente com achar que está acima do bem e do mal e não pode ser criticado, é não aceitar a opinião dos outros, é achar que o que vale para os outros não vale para você. Arrogância é ruim, mas quando ela se junta com a ignorância se torna explosiva e afunda a pessoa e todos que estiverem à sua volta. Não é fácil criar ilhas de combate a essa situação.

O sistema é feito para que todos possam participar conforme vão ganhando privilégios e se tornam mais confiáveis. É preciso esforço e comprometimento para se tornar confiável e é preciso ser convincente nas suas demandas, então se vai reclamar, prepare-se e não jogue no ventilador e saia correndo. Só reclamar que os outros estão errados é fácil, mas não tem valor.

Algumas críticas são pertinentes, mas nem sempre podemos resolver o problema.

Eu tenho certeza que não fazemos o melhor possível aqui, mas fazemos o melhor que conseguimos agora dentro das condições que temos. Eu não sei o que mais fazer pra melhorar, mas sei que algumas coisas não dão certo, eu estou há anos aqui observando tudo o que acontece e tentando fazer minha parte.

A ferramenta nem sempre ajuda. Eu sou crítico dela, mas não temos controle sobre tudo. O SO ainda é um site acima da média e ainda temos mais condição de manter a qualidade do que em outros lugares.

A qualidade já foi melhor, por isso o conteúdo mais antigo tem mais valia para a maioria das pessoas.

Algumas pessoas dizem que aqui é pior que o SO em inglês. Outras dizem o oposto. Que eu me lembre todo mundo que passou maus bocados aqui foram tentar lá e quebraram a cara também. Às vezes escapa algumas coisas porque lá são milhares de novas perguntas por dia, muitas vezes o pessoal nem tem condições de monitorar tudo. E é verdade que já fomos mais condescendentes aqui, mas compare as postagens de hoje com as do passado, cada ano temos uma piora no nível da perguntas, até mesmo das pessoas experientes no site, afinal [quando você vê algo ruim acha que pode fazer o mesmo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/44/101).

Pra quem critica e não vem fazer sua parte eu só tenho algo a dizer: vai catar coquinho na beira da estrada.

Vem dar *feedback* para todos os usuários que postam perguntas ruins, vem editar tudo, deixar as perguntas em bom estado e aí quem sabe dar uma boa resposta quando a pergunta já está boa. Mesmo que essa pessoa faça isto ela poderia gastar mais energia tentando dar ótimas respostas, então até se ela fizer o que diz para os outros fazerem está prejudicando a comunidade como um todo, a não ser que ela consiga fazer as duas coisas, mas consegue? Eu não consigo. Acha que faço pouco pela comunidade?

Muitas dessas pessoas discursam e se autointitulam pessoas de comunidade, dizem que trabalham em equipe, mas elas só o fazem se for tudo do jeito delas, não conseguem trabalhar em equipe que não seja definida por elas. Eu tive que abrir mão de muita coisa aqui para poder fazer parte desta de comunidade, se fosse do meu jeito seria muito diferente do que é.

Enquanto essas pessoas só criticarem e se afastarem de fazer sua parte, elas serão apenas *trolls* ou *haters*. Deixarão de ser quando fizerem algo produtivo.

Uma frase tirada aqui do meta que acho que define bem o que acontece aqui quando há uma reclamação do que fazemos aqui:

> Seria como a pessoa ir a um restaurante vegetariano e achar ruim que não servem carne lá. Você não é obrigado a comprar carne, mas eles não são obrigados a vender isto.

[image: seja a mudança que quer ver no mundo]

Algumas discussões que já rolaram aqui:

- [Quem vigia os vigilantes?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5679/101)
- [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/101)
- [É possível (e desejável) reduzir o requisito para comentar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/817/101)
- [moderação agressiva: é o que queremos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5348/101)
- [Stackoverflow não é uma boa opção para quem quer começar a programar!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4818/101)
- [O que está acontecendo com o Stack PT?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7586/101)
- [Deveríamos qualificar os votos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4865/101)
- [Não entendo votos negativos, e você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4948/101)
- [Tratamento diferente para perguntas parecidas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7508/101)
- [Qual o critério para dizer se uma pergunta é ampla demais?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7449/101)
- [Obrigar quem deu downvote a comentar o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4126/101)
- [Peço desculpa a todos, mas quero fazer uma reclamação sobre downvoter?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1916/101)
- [Votos negativos em uma pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6386/101)
- [Negativamento de perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5439/101)
- [Pergunta ampla ou simplesmente não foi devidamente compreendida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7626/101)
- [Votar no conteudo VS Votar por afeição](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6021/101)

O que mais você acrescentaria?

Comment: Esta thread ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101615) - quem quiser acrescentar algo pode utilizar o link.