# 6 anos de Stack Overflow em Português!

Tags: debate, comunidade

## Precisamos de mais comunidade!

Normalmente eu gosto de comemorar o aniversário do site. Em anos anteriores tivemos números interessantes para mostrar e muito o que comemorar (nem tanto no último).

Este ano o ponto principal talvez seja a queda de qualidade do conteúdo geral, mas principalmente das perguntas. Quase não se pergunta mais o que sempre gostamos, algo que ajude muita gente, algo que ajude o site ser mais visitado, que traga gente que queira aprender. Hoje a grande maioria das perguntas são pedidos de ajuda individual que tem uma chance muito pequena ou nula de ajudar outra pessoa, não só pelo assunto, mas também pela forma que ela é feita.

Não ajuda o fato de algumas pessoas quererem responder assim mesmo, ou por causa dos pontos, ou porque acham que podem ajudar mesmo que não seja o caso no formato da pergunta, por ingenuidade de como essas coisas descarrilham rápido ou porque ela mesma não entende o quanto aquilo é problemático ou outro motivo. E isto tem se tornado fonte de conflitos constantes.

Por tudo isso não tem muito o que comemorar, chegamos aqui em situação bastante crítica. O peso desses conflitos está ficando muito grande, o custo de manter a qualidade está alto. Aquela ideia de ser um site de pouco ruído já não existe mais, de um jeito ou de outro há muito mais ruído do que sinal limpo.

Algumas pessoas reclamam que é desanimador não conseguir fazer uma pergunta bem aceita. Imagine quem está há 6 anos todos os dias aqui, lidando com isso o tempo todo. É frustrante ver cada vez mais perguntas ruins e cada vez menos interesse ou capacidade das pessoas de resolver os problemas. É desestimulante ver até mesmo alguns membros ativos que não dão valor para isto ou não ajudam manter a ordem (sem querer cobrar que essas pessoas tenham obrigação de fazer mais do que já fazem, mas fazer quase tudo sozinho não é fácil).

E não sei que adjetivo usar para expressar a contrariedade das mudanças recentes da SE tornando a plataforma mais propensa a ter esses conteúdos ruins e sem mudar nada para lidar melhor com isso (imagine se ela cogitaria a ideia que alguns tem de começar a pergunta fechada e abrir se ela merecer, já que hoje em dia tem consideravelmente mais conteúdo ruim do que bom).

Tudo isso me faz pensar se vale a pena esse esforço todo que tenho e se vale o esforço de outros. Claro que não posso falar por todos, mas faço uma pergunta até para não ficar só como uma anti comemoração ou desabafo. Você acha que o esforço atual que acredito estar maior que antes para manter a qualidade e o resultado obtido está valendo a pena?

Considere ainda que falta apoio e sobram críticas.

Será que não é outra de deixar a qualidade pra lá, se conformar com o que foi feito no passado valeu a pena e agora só temos um site como outro qualquer de ajuda individual que não tem mais presunção de qualidade?

Não seria melhor mudarmos nossa postura?

São perguntas reais, não estou propondo isto. Até porque se mudar não sei se tenho interesse mais em continuar no site, ele passa ser algo quase igual ao Yahoo! Respostas que sempre foi tão criticado aqui. Ok, tem algumas vantagens, mas o Y!R tem algumas respostas boas no meio de tanta ruim. Será que não vai acontecer isso com o SOpt daqui 6 anos e não acharmos mais as boas facilmente.

O padrão de votação já indica que não há nem valor mais para as coisas antigas. Sempre tinha novos votos aqui e ali, isto praticamente desapareceu. Não há mais uma classificação consistente, não votam suficiente para cima ou para baixo.

Quando diziam que no Brasil este tipo de site com regras mais rígidas não daria certo, eu, equivocadamente, dizia que não. Não que o pessoal de Portugal tenha contribuído de forma muito melhor.

De fato quase todo mundo que ajudava muito o site se afastou ou diminuiu bem a atividade. Não quero dizer que agora só tem pessoas com um postura que não ajuda, mas essas que ajudam se tornaram escassas e insuficiente para lidar com tanto problema.

É fato que está todo mundo cansado, em vários pontos não vemos participação que demanda qualquer esforço adicional salvo um espasmo aqui ali de um ou outro usuário. Este *post* não gerará muita repercussão. Não como antes.

A culpa não é de todo do SOpt, parece que a sociedade está caminhando rápido para um lado bastante desagradável, o que acontece aqui parece ser só reflexo disto. Eu ainda não acho certo assentar esta postura, mas não sei quanto mais forças terei para tentar fazer o que acredito ser o certo dentro da evidência empírica que tenho do que dava certo e agora o que não dá. Me frustra muito ver tanta gente indo como um trem desgovernado e eu não conseguir convencê-las disto. Talvez eu esteja errado, mas se não estiver todo pagarão um preço alto.

Não é a toa que temos a primeira geração de pessoas que ganham menos que seus pais, na média, na mesma idade. E a distribuição de renda nunca foi tão afetada pela (falta de) educação de alguns em comparação aos que conseguem melhores resultados. Educação no sentido amplo. Também não é de surpreender que o Brasil foi considerado o país com população que está mais afastada da realidade no mundo (nenhum país se saiu bem, mas o Brasil foi inacreditável, tudo é achismo, fazem relações completamente absurdas, acreditam em coisas sem sentido, por isso tantas perguntas partem de premissas erradas e até a participação no site fica comprometida, ninguém quer entender o que de fato está acontecendo).

Eu não sei o que fazer, tenho um tempo para decidir meu futuro no site, que pode ir para qualquer lado em qualquer graduação, e posso mudar quando eu achar que devo. Mas não é fácil continuar assim, sem apoio, sem reconhecimento, sem nenhum tipo de ganho mesmo intangível, não é fácil. Eu fiz o que pude e farei mais se ainda puder.

Eu gosto de sempre agradecer aos que colaboraram para manter o site em alta mesmo com todas essas dificuldades. Me desculpem os erros que cometi, sempre foi com boa intenção e talvez pelo volume de atividade já que poucos colaboram.

As perguntas não são retóricas, é para responder mesmo.

## O SOpt ainda é um site que não aceita tudo

Comment: Um pensamento que eu estava tendo hoje, que é relacionado à sua questão: se a moderação está em desacordo com a comunidade (no geral, não só com alguns usuários específicos), até que ponto a moderação está representando-a? Sabemos que tempos mudam e que interesses mudam. Devemos mudar a moderação ou devemos mudar a comunidade? Até agora foi tentado, sem êxito, mudar a comunidade.

Comment: @Woss de certa forma concordo. Não da maneira que talvez vc espere, mas eu também acho que moderar algo contra a filosofia da empresa dona desse algo é improdutivo. Quando eu entrei era bem clara a filosofia. Aparentemente mudou, mas ninguém oficializou (e eu pedi muito isso para o CM da época, mas nunca veio qualquer mudança oficial a não ser algumas coisas MUITO recentes, que fogem da discussão aqui).

Comment: Para clarificar: não sugeri mudar a moderação; eu não tenho opinião formada sobre e só quis compartilhar o pensamento. Mas compactuo que **pode acontecer** de um moderador julgar que a comunidade não faz à altura quando ele passa a discordar desta e deixa de representá-la. Neste seria o caso de o moderador deixar o cargo aceitando que a comunidade não é mais aquilo que era, análogo à questão que usuários precisam entender que o SOpt não é o site que buscam. Essa fronteira, de quando um moderador "precisa largar a toalha" é bem complicada de definir, pelo menos para mim.

Comment: Sobre "a moderação est[ar] em desacordo com a comunidade", então pergunto: que comunidade/fatia estamos falando aqui? Se é uma fatia de neófitos considerável, então eles não deveriam ser considerados [inicialmente] como "forasteiros"?, e, portanto, não "membros" da comunidade? Ou deveríamos acolher todos como "cidadãos de primeira classe"? Assim sendo, a "comunidade original" deveria estar sujeita a ser sobreposta por uma onda de novatos e aceitar a vontade da maioria? Fica o questionamento em definir "comunidade"...

Comment: Quando tem de ser a moderação em vez dos CM's a fazerem estas publicações já fica tudo dito ;)

Comment: Uma coisa é certa, se a falta da SE aqui tem um mal, também tem um bem. A comunidade é que decide aqui. Se algumas pessoas se comprometerem com isto eu sou pessoa de voltar ao ativo. Mas sou sincero não tenho tempo nem vontade de fazer o trabalho todo que fazes ou perto disso. Se for para dividir para conquistar conta comigo.

Comment: O problema não é a comunidade, o problema está numa geração que passou por um processo de degradação intelectual que não tem consciência disso e acredita que ser hedonista é uma coisa normal e aceitável, e essa geração está chegado a vida universitária ou está a margeando. No que tange a comunidade, o processo conflituoso que estamos vivendo, é devido a está absorção que gera um choque cultural entra a comunidade que valoriza o mérito, esforço e conhecimento e os novatos que estão chegando que valorizam o prazer prazer, imediatismo e resolução imediata de seu próprios problemas.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É uma questão ainda mais interessante. Até que ponto devemos ser saudosistas e lamentar por aquilo que a comunidade era (e deixou de ser) e quando deveríamos adotar, mesmo a contra-gosto, a "nova" comunidade.

Comment: Eu não tenho a solução para esse problema, estou elencando o que vejo mas durante esses seis anos(pelo menos o que consegui absorver pelo Meta e as publicações mais antigas no ptSO) a quantidade desses hedonistas era baixa e então a comunidade os escarrava, esse faziam um post no facebook ou twitter alegando que o SO e formado por narcisistas, arrogantes e que nunca mais entraria e ponto final. Agora o volume é de uma enxurrada e nós, responsabilidade minha também, temos que bolar um meio de lidar com essas pessoa e ajudar traze-las para a realidade e mostrar do que se trata o ptSO....

Comment: ...pois o ptSO é uma coisa que elas nunca vivenciaram.

Comment: A SE já deixou claro muitas vezes que prefere quantidade à qualidade; a comunidade está gerando quantidade ao invés de qualidade. Talvez seja a hora de aceitarmos que somos nós o problema e que o site não é o que queríamos que fosse.

Comment: @Woss realmemente é uma questão de hoje, não era de ontem, não era da semana passada, não era do mês passado, não era do ano passado. Eu vivo postando coisas questionando se o caminho estava certo, e de forma geral todos os ativos, inclusive você sempre apoiaram, agora por causa de um caso que era do interesse vai mudar de opinião? Me parece que seu interesse mudou. Ok, se for o mesmo pra outras pessoas, mudamos. A pergunta é mais uma tentativa de ver se precisa mudar. Isso terá consequência, espero que não seja porque alguém não gostou de uma ação específica, aí dará errado.

Comment: A comunidade não faz tanto quanto deveria. E a discussão que houve em outro chat paralelo mostra muito isso. Cobraram de mim mais comentários específicos quando a comunidade não está fazendo isto. É o que eu postei em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8047/101. Eu não dou conta de fazer tudo. A comunidade precisa fazer mais para cobrar que outros o façam. Não querem fazer? Não tem problema, deixe quem quer fazer e não reclamem.

Comment: @Woss (Parte II) fiz o primeiro comentário sobre a empresa. Agora sobre comunidade, vamos pegar meu caso como exemplo: fui eleito faz 1 ano e pouco, e quem votou em mim votou em uma proposta. A proposta não mudou nesse um ano. Ou seja, se tem alguém que representa a comunidade são os moderadores eleitos, não? A não ser que quem tenha votado não represente a comunidade, claro... mas se for esse critério, vai ser sempre um cachorro correndo atrás do rabo então (vamos precisar eleger o "moderador da semana" para acompanhar a volatilidade da comunidade).

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pra mim comunidade é quem participa, comunidade é quem faz , o peso de cada um é de acordo com o que faz (como é oficialmente em cooperativa), você já fez muito, tem muito peso, hoje faz menos, o peso diminuiu, mas ainda tem muito crédito. Quem chega, não entende nada e dá uma opinião sem conhecer de fato as dores do site e quase certo que vai embora logo não tem peso. Quem ajuda com perguntas ou respostas, mas não faz mais nada tem um peso bem baixo, mesmo que faça bastante porque a pessoa não participa de fato da comunidade como um todo.

Comment: @JorgeB. infelizmente mesmo sem parecer a SE tem tomado algumas ações que empurrar a comunidade pra um lado sem obrigar fazer nada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques considero sua avaliação bastante correta e precisa, mas a comunidade agindo pouco está assinando embaixo disto. Eu adoraria ter uma foma melhor de lidar com isso que não seja "vamos transformar isso aqui em Facebook".

Comment: @Maniero . Um caminho, quase que imediato, para tornar a comunidade mais ativa seria se a SE permitisse que quantidade de votos comunitários necessários para fechar e reabrir uma pergunta passassem de 5 votos para 3 votos, isso tornaria muito mais ágeis os processos de moderação e daria aos membros comunitários uma sensação de maior de contribuição na melhoria do conteúdo. Pessoalmente posso fazer é verificar se já não existe essa tentativa mas pretendo criar um post, de fácil digestão, relacionando os privilégios adquiridos com a reputação com o papel e as responsabilidades dos novatos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques infelizmente essas coisas não tem como passar, já temos experiência, coisa até que a SE concorda não andam fazendo (esse exemplo é de algo tem algumas complicações técnicas para fazer aqui e não em outros sites, só pra pegar um ponto mais concreto). Outra ideia que também não rolará é dar direito a mais votos para quem é muito ativo ou tem grande reputação. 40 votos por dia não dá para negativar tudo o que é ruim no dia. Mas de qq forma seria paliativo pela baixa atividade dos outros membros da comunidade.

Comment: @Todos. Eu acho que precisaria eleger mais dois moderadores, estou falando de aumentar o quadro de moderadores e não motim, com responsabilidades específicas, para aliviar o fardo dos moderadores atuais. Seria um para promover os valores e a identidade do ptSO e outro para enquadrar e direcionar os novatos. Ou delegar moderação temporária ao usuários com mais tempo e mais ativos para medir qual o impacto na comunidade.

Comment: @Maniero Não sei dizer se minha visão mudou de fato, mas estou bem propenso a isso. Vejo que *nadar contra a corrente* está gerando estresse demais para todas as partes e manter assim também não é saudável para a comunidade. Também não consigo avaliar se vale a pena seguir como estamos fazendo priorizando a qualidade ou se deixamos a barca seguir o fluxo natural. Praticamente tudo o que víamos como necessário para resolver os problemas dependiam da SE e eles nunca mostraram interesse em mudar; é uma luta perdida que eu já não vejo vantagem em manter.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Acho que isso ajuda mas não resolve, a quantidade de gente nova que chega todo dia e não quer saber das regras é grande demais. Acho que o próprio site deveria instruir novos usuários, aliviando o fardo dos poucos que ainda tentam fazer isso. Coisas como [essa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), por exemplo, seriam **muito** mais eficientes nesse sentido, mas as prioridades da empresa parecem ser [isso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/401803) e [isso](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/)

Comment: @Woss então mudando de posição estaria dizendo "vamos deixar como é o Facebook ou outro site qualquer e não importa a qualidade"? É uma pergunta legítima, não estou sendo irônico, quero entender se aceita as consequências disto, na hipótese levantada.

Comment: @Maniero Basicamente, sim. Hoje não vejo garantias de que a SE irá reconhecer todo o nosso esforço para manter a qualidade, já deu indícios de que pode mudar tudo para pior sem aviso prévio e sem consultar a comunidade; é um investimento unilateral, sem retorno. Para mim, está parecendo que chegou a hora de dar à SE o site que ela quer e lavarmos as mãos. Aceitar que o site não é aquilo que queríamos e que provavelmente nunca será.

Comment: Se problema é popularização, porque não direcionar os neófitos mais populares ou imediatistas para o chat principal?Lá eles terão a possibilidade de expor seus problemas em uma comunicação mais coloquial e menos regidos a regras da comunidade, com direito a slogan "Se você é rebelde e averso as regras conheça o chat da nossa comunidade". O único compromisso seria sair uma pergunta/resposta no site após a sessão.

Comment: @Maniero se você reparar está mais para fórum que para facebook. Nos fóruns é que se faziam perguntas especificas. Respondia-se o que se achava e pronto, nunca mais ninguém queria saber. A sorte do SO é que tem muita informação boa antiga. Mas quando essa info começar a ficar desatualizada vai surgir outro site qualquer que vai acabar com este.

Comment: @JorgeB. não faz muita diferença, e o FB está sendo usado como fórum em alguns grupos. A única diferença é que aqui não pode ofender e fazer bullying claro. Acho curioso que o pessoa chega ficar tão perdido que pra obter uma resposta maluca qualquer aceita passar por isso lá.

Comment: Acho que a preocupação em termos de qualidade está muito concentrada num lado só (qualidade das perguntas, por exemplo) enquanto que a qualidade das pessoas em si é meio que deixada de lado: perseguições, votos negativos porque um não gosta ou não vai com a cara do outro, ou o contrário: votos positivos em perguntas/respostas ruins pq tem simpatia com o autor e por aí vai.

Comment: @Sam sim, nós moderadores vemos perseguições bastante porque temos acesso aos padrões de voto, algumas brancas, que não são de ficar dando negativos, você acha que deve fazer algo com caso assim? A gente até gostaria, mas é um pouco complicado fazer isto porque a pessoa sempre pode alegar que gosta muito de algo de uma pessoa (desde que não tenha outras evidências de manipulação) e a pessoa pode alegar que nada do que uma pessoa pessoa posta é boa então ela não merece positivos. Claro que há um padrão que dá para saber que é mentira, mas não chega ser uma prova. Então nos concretamos no que

Comment: pode ser provado e algumas coisas subimos para os CMs decidirem, pena que alguns estão lá há meses sem resposta. Se fosse simples muita gente estaria suspensa, inclusive vários que estão na primeira página. Infelizmente isso se tornou prática comum. Mas aceitamos sugestões de como ser mais rígidos quanto a isto. Indícios temos, mas precisamos de algo que não pode ser contestado. Vamos dizer que tenha indícios que você vota ou deixa de votar em certas pessoas e não tem algo mais que indique de forma clara que isso seja manipulação você gostaria de ser suspenso?

Comment: Claro, ninguém gosta de ser suspenso, a maioria é contestada, mas se tem algo mais concreto fica difícil a pessoa reclamar. Por isso algumas pessoas ainda não foram suspensas mesmo vendo que ela é tendenciosa quando vota. Para esses casos virou regra normal, para sorte de alguns.

Comment: Acabei de ver que recebeu negativo em uma pergunta sua que depois foi apagada, então não sei o quanto essa sugestão não é só reação a isto. Sse acha que foi por perseguição é justamente o problema que eu falei, não dá para ter certeza, pode ter sido um motivo legítimo. Eu olhei por cima porque o assunto não me interessa e não vi nada errado, mas alguém pode ter visto. E existe o voto errado mesmo, que não tem um motivo válido, mas tem um que a pessoa achou, isso não é perseguição. Você mesmo já negativou coisa minha que tinha uns 10 positivos.

Comment: Justificou o voto e todo mundo achou inválido, mas você achou que era merecido, isto foi perseguição? Não, só discordância de opinião, talvez teimosia com tanta gente achando o contrário. Esse tipo de coisa acontece, mas é até pouco pelo que eu percebo.

Comment: @sam por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428227/101 aqui teve um negativo aqui hoje. Tem vários indícios que a pessoa votou por perseguição que não vou dizer porque para não dar pistas para as pessoas disfarçarem melhor, mas a parte boa é que a pessoa vai se enforcando e logo poderá ser suspensa por esse motivo. Algumas pessoas não conseguem resistir, mesmo sabendo que será pega. Ou talvez ela não entendeu o que eu escrevi aqui e achou que eu disse que a pessoa pode fazer o que bem entender e não será punida.

Comment: Eu tenho sido negativado sistematicamente que nem ligo mais.

Comment: @Sam na verdade você não é tão negativado assim, mal está entre os 10 mais negativados, tem cerca de 20% do negativos que eu tenho. Além do que boa parte das suas respostas são questionadas pelas pessoas, a maioria dos negativos que recebo não tem nada da pessoa falando porque teve o negativo, boa parte deles vem de pessoas que percebe-se ter uma padrão sistemático de votos contra mim e eventualmente mais alguém que ela considerou desafeto e quase não tem negativos em outras pessoas, o que é um dos indicadores de possível perseguição.

Comment: Os negativos em você são muito distribuídos, tem um descolamento apenas e indicadores que dá o que pensar, mas não vou falar para não dar informação sobre o seu padrão de voto. Este caso poderia ser perseguição, mas ela não ocorre mais e se for fazer algo teria complicadores que não vou falar para não dar dicas. Se acha que tem perseguição ainda precisa dar indicativos mais fortes.

Comment: @Maniero Esse negativo não tem como justificar a resposta é um caso de uso dum padrão de fachada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não entendi.

Comment: @Maniero Nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428227/101

Comment: Ah sim, esse é um caso claro de perseguição (porque tem outros indicadores), por mim já teria punição, mas como eu estaria punindo a pessoa que negativou por algo feito contra mim acaba ficando por isso mesmo, pegaria mal eu fazer algo contra quem me prejudicou. Tem coisas minhas que merecem ou possivelmente merecem negativo, mas tem muitos casos que é só retaliação porque eu fechei algo ou porque a pessoa pensa que eu negativei algo e é fácil pegar isso. Era melhor quando eu não era moderador um CM que nem gostava de mim tirava esses negativos porque a perseguição era clara.

Comment: Acredito que a missão de vocês seja ajudar a resolver problemas, sendo eles fáceis, difíceis. Já estive três dias na frente de um código que estava com um erro óbvio, mas estava com os olhos viciados e não era mais capaz de ver o erro. Eu olhava para ele mas não via. E se nesse momento um moderador ou usuário qualquer,desse a dica certa. Resolve-se o problema e deixa o programador seguir codificando. Essa é a missão do Stack overflow, ou não? Quando alguém procura ajuda é por que já tentou de tudo, varias tentativas, muita leitura de manuais. SEJAM FLEXÍVEIS.