# Ganhei medalhas em massa, o que ocorreu?

Tags: bug

Hoje quando cheguei me deparei com isto:

> [image: medalhas em massa]

Ocorreu tudo hoje, de uma vez.

Quero lembrar que a alguns anos (anos mesmo) falei com um CM (staff) e um moderador sobre receber essa mesma medalha por postagens que nunca compartilhei e nunca tinha visto, a resposta que recebi foi:

> Você deve ter compartilhado e não se lembra

A não ser que eu sofra de algum problema grave de memória a anos eu realmente tinha certeza de na época nunca ter acessado tais postagens, eram postagens inclusive que eu nem tinha interesse nas tecnologias, a probabilidade era praticamente zero, mas não discuti, só insisti que me parecia um bug da SO.

Ok, fiz o que pude, até então hoje receber diversas medalhas sobre o **compartilhamento por 25 ips únicos**, para quem não sabe essa medalha é ganha apenas quando você gera um link de compartilhamento associado ao seu ID, por exemplo se for em uma postagem e clicar em:

> [image: compartilhar postagem]

Note que o link gerado não é "normal":

```
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8091/3635
```

O `/3635` é o meu ID pessoal, ou seja se 25 pessoas (com IPs diferentes é claro) acessarem este link irei ganhar a medalha (que pode ser ganhada várias vezes para diferentes links gerados).

### Especulações

1. Então imagino eu que talvez a SO tenha corrigido o suposto BUG que eu imaginava que poderia existir, e por isto links que compartilhei durante todos esses anos e que eu deveria ter recebido medalhas começaram a ser entregues agora.
2. A SO removeu algumas medalhas e teve que reajustar o sistema para alguns dados que iriam se perder, por isto o sistema teve que recalcular todas medalhas que seriam perdidas e entregar novamente a todos, no meu caso as de compartilhamento

---

Então a duvida é, o que aconteceu de fato?

Comment: Provavelmente é isso: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340289/401803

Comment: @hkotsubo apesar de afirmarem uma coisa sobre melhorar a query eu presumo que tinha sim BUG na query deles para avaliar isto, o que deve ter ocasionado as medalhas que nem tinha relação comigo -.-

Comment: Eu ganhei algumas também.

Comment: @LINQ estou tentando checar se foram medalhas que eu tinha ganhado antes e eles zeraram e refizeram os cálculos, ou simplesmente foram medalhas que o sistema me devia por erro nos calculos anteriores (o problema de calculo conforme o link q o hktsubo enviou não deu detalhes, só falou que havia um problema)